# Vertical alignment & line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a trouble in drawing a simple diagram with tikz.
What I want is a diagram that lines are drawn between left aligned nodes.
But the vertical alignment make the line tilted/slanted which looks ugly (see the example below). 
How can I prevent this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base west}]
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, row sep=5mm] {
\node (X) {X_{i}}; \\
\node (Y) {Y_{ij}}; \\
\node (Z) {Z_{ijk}}; \\
};
\draw (X) -- (Y);
\draw (Y) -- (Z);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={anchor=base west}]
\matrix [matrix of math nodes, row sep=5mm] {
\node (X) {X_{i}}; \\
\node (Y) {Y_{ij}}; \\
\node (Z) {Z_{ijk}}; \\
};
\draw (X) -- (Y.north -| X); % <--- added -| X for determining coordinate 
                             % cross vertical line through middle of X 
                             % and horizontal through north of Y
\draw (Y) -- (Z.north -| X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want. Can I find your trick (or something related) somewhere in the manual?

Comment: Concept I described in comment in the code. In TikZ manual is mentioned in 13.3 Coordinates at Intersections, page 137 (in the recent version)

Answer (score 0):

This could be a job for `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=dash]
X_{i} \arrow[d] \\
Y_{ij} \arrow[d] \\
Z_{ijk}
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As for lines this is perfect. Can we align the components?

Comment: @Orat It depends on what alignment you're thinking to